# cProfile, how to understand why lambda function is most time consuming call

Tags: python, lambda, cprofile

I'm new to cprofile but I'm running it on a python tool written for ArcGIS.  It tells me that the most time consuming function is the lambda function in _base.py:

| ncalls | tottime | percall | cumtime | percall | filename:lineno(function) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17875 | 137.877 | 0.008 | 200.404 | 0.011 | `_base.py:510(<lambda>)` |
| 962732 | 67.568 | 0 | 67.568 | 0 | `{built-in method createobject}` |
| 7497 | 44.223 | 0.006 | 44.223 | 0.006 | `{built-in method distanceto}` |
| 8301909/8300996 | 35.652 | 0 | 35.659 | 0 | `{getattr}` |
| 713 | 35.235 | 0.049 | 35.235 | 0.049 | `{built-in method listfields}` |

_base.py is an arcpy file in this location:

C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.8\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing

How can I dig deeper and find out what's using this lambda function?

The tool is over 5000 lines of code so I can't post it but I'm importing cprofile at the start:

```
    import cProfile, pstats
    profiler = cProfile.Profile()
    profiler.enable()
```

then disabling it and dumping the stats just before the end:

```
    profiler.disable()
    stats.dump_stats(myStatsLocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I need to debug slow code, I use [line profiler](https://github.com/pyutils/line_profiler).
Using this you can use decorator on suspect slow functions.
From there, you can find out, like with cProfiler, what's being called and how many times.

The cProfiler already pinpoints to line 510 in your `_base.py`.
So probably that lambda calls another function which is slow.
Adding the `@profile` on that function might shed some light on your performance issues.